# How to set access to GWC urls in GeoServer?

Tags: geowebcache, authentication

I published a service in GeoServer successfully and now I want to set user access to my demo url (http://myip:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo).

Everybody can see my demo url without any login and grant and this is my issue. How can I limit access to the url with authentication?

Comment: why? everyone accessing your tiles is a good thing, the demo just saves them digging out their own client.